# Map application doesn't work?

Tags: android-maps

Now, i have followed the instructions on developers.android to the T. My android api key is correct, i am using the library in manifest, i have permissions for internet and fine locations. I am even getting grey tiles. i have directly installed the app. on the xperia x10. Its native map application works, i dont understand why mine doesn't. Any Help?

P.S.- already asked the question in another thread.. still qiting for answers..:(

Comment: If you post your MapActivity class, your layout and your manifest, you would be much more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually had one peculiar problem with the Xperia X10, in that the map tiles would not load if my permissions were declared **below** the application tag in the manifest. On every other device it worked like a charm.

Also, you are aware that you need a different api key for development (debug) and production?